# looping in R efficent programming

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, mathematical-optimization

I have the following program. I just want to run the for loop and save the results from each iteration into `valg[i,]`, `valo[i,]` and `obj[i,]` matrix/table

I'm doing something incorrectly, I get the following error

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, , value = c(80.6413039191413, 40.0368791515846,  : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

This program requires DEoptim package

I would greatly appreciate any help

```
g = matrix(c(1,6,1,1,1/6,
             1/6,1,6,1,1,
             1,1/6,1,6,1,
             1,1,1/6,1,6,
             6,1,1,1/6,1
             ), nrow=5, ncol=5)

a <- t(g)

lsm <- function(x){
  b <- a - outer(x,x,`/`)
  z <- sum(b^2)
  return(z)}

for (i in (1 : 10)){

outDEoptim <- DEoptim(lsm, lower = rep(0.001,nrow(a)), 
                      upper = rep(100,nrow(a)),DEoptim.control(trace = FALSE))

  valg[i,] = rbind(outDEoptim$member$bestmemit[200,]) ## Save for each itr i and input to optim below for each itr 

  lsmoptl <- optim(par=c(valg[i,]), fn=lsm, gr = NULL,
                 method = c("L-BFGS-B"))
  valo[i,] = lsmoptl$par/sum(lsmoptl$par) ## Save for each itr i 

  obj[i,] = lsmoptl$value ## Save for each itr i 
}
```

Comment: You haven't created (or shown us how you created) `valg` or `obj`.  Without those, we cannot help much.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you forgot to post them and it is not the problem, you have to first initialize the object valg (and the others) for it to allow storing in indices.

For instance:

```
valg <- matrix(1, nrow=10, ncol=3)
```

will initialize the object.

From then on you can store in it using a loop.

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    valg[i, ] <- 1:3
}
```

You may want to read some R tutorials online before posting elementary R issues.